# Connection handling in EJB2 session beans

Tags: connection, ejb, connection-pooling, ejb-2.x

I recently started maintaining an old EJB2 application running on OC4J. That includes EJB doclet and other horrible horrible things. Currently, each method creates a `ConnectionFactory` that queries JNDI for a `Datasource`, which then creates a connection. This leads to a lot of boiler plate code.

My question now is: is it safe to do this only once per stateless session bean, and reuse the same connection? `ejbCreate()` would get the connection from JNDI, and then close it in `ejbRemove()`.
Would this be good or bad design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposed design will have unpredictable behavior, as the life cycle methods are handled by the container. Stateless session bean are pooled by the container(in most cases) & same instance can be served to multiple requests.

The methods `ejbCreate()` and `ejbRemove()` are invoked by the container when the bean is initialized first time & when it is removed from the pool respectively. Therefore it may open a connection in `ejbCreate()`, but may not close it & service requests with the same connection.

But, if connection is opened & the bean remains idle in the pool, it will hold up resource unnecessarily, may end up in exceptions like socket timeout, too many opened connections etc.

Its better to write a generalize method for opening/closing connection, to utilize the resources properly.

---

**Edit :** From Core J2EE Patterns - Service Locator

> Use a Service Locator object to abstract all JNDI usage and to hide
>   the complexities of initial context creation, EJB home object lookup,
>   and EJB object re-creation. Multiple clients can reuse the Service
>   Locator object to reduce code complexity, provide a single point of
>   control, and improve performance by providing a caching facility.

Comment: How about other session beans? Are those safe to "cache" (initialize in ejbCreate) in session beans, like I'm currently doing with connections?

Comment: Please refer edit part for caching of stateless beans, these beans should not contain instance variables.

Comment: Note that it is advisable to have instance variables if they consume resources & are shareable, like caching of some data from database.